# GStreamer d3dvideosink overlay repaint flicker

Tags: qt, gstreamer, direct3d, flicker

I've got a quite persistent problem regarding the **d3dvideosink**.

My GStreamer pipeline is written by using the GStreamer SDK 1.14.2 in Qt/C++ and looks like this:
*videotestsrc -> d3dvideosink*

I use `gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle` to place the sinks output over the corresponding QWidget (using `WId QWidget::winId() const`).

The stream works as expected, but will produce flicker whenever the widget (or any parent widget) is repainting (e.g. while resizing).

[image: Flicker]

How can I configure the widget / pipeline / d3dvideosink / ... to eliminate flickers ?

P.S. Using glimagesink instead of d3dvideosink works, but will be less performant.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Qt repaints over the Window. To do this:

1. setAttribute(Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen);
2. Overload paintEngine() to return nullptr.

Comment: Will have a go on this once I'm back at work. Thanks!